# Identify the orders that could be honored depending on the products that we have in the warehouse

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, sql-server-2022

I have 2 tables one is Warehouse with prodid and prodname
then the Orders table where we have OrderNo and RequiredProdName

What is the requirement?

To identify the orders that could be honored and completed depending on the products that we have in the warehouse.

Let's take ord001, it should contain Prod007, Prod008 and Prod009 from the warehouse. If these products exists in the warehouse, then the order is fulfilled and this 3 products exists and so ord001 should appear in the final solution.

Let's take ord002, it should contain Prod008, Prod009 and Prod012 if they exists in the warehouse. Prod008 exists in the warehouse and even if one Prod008 was taken in the first order ord001 there is still 1 because we have 2 pieces in the warehouse but Prod009 in the warehouse is only one piece and already send it to order001 and Prod012 can be honored as we still have 1 piece in warehouse, this order002 should NOT appear in the output because although Prod008 and Prod012 can be honored for Prod009 we no longer have - there was just one product and that went to first order.

Let's take ord003, this order contains 2 products, Prod008 of which we still have 1 in inventory and Prod014, of which we still have 1 in inventory, so this order can be honored because we have these products, items in the warehouse.

Final output : ord001 and ord003

It's something recursive to look back to see if that product was allocated or not.

I have created the Dbfiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/3vYH2i6B with ddl and dml statements and i put there my attemp but i m far away from the correct output and i really don t know how to solve this task so please bear with me.

Also i will add the tables here:
Orders

| OrderNo | RequiredProdName |
| --- | --- |
| ORD001 | Prod007 |
| ORD001 | Prod008 |
| ORD001 | Prod009 |
| ORD002 | Prod008 |
| ORD002 | Prod009 |
| ORD002 | Prod012 |
| ORD003 | Prod008 |
| ORD003 | Prod014 |

Warehouse

| ProdId | ProdName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Prod007 |
| 2 | Prod008 |
| 3 | Prod008 |
| 4 | Prod012 |
| 5 | Prod009 |
| 6 | Prod014 |
| 7 | Prod015 |

What i have tried:

```
WITH orders1 AS (
    select orderno, requiredprodname, rn_order, stock, demand, stock-demand as remaining
    from (
        SELECT
            o.orderno,
            o.requiredprodname, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY o.orderno ORDER BY o.requiredprodname) AS rn_order,
            stock,
            count(o.requiredprodname) over(partition by o.orderno, o.requiredprodname) as demand
        FROM orders o
        left join (
            select prodname, count(*) As stock
            from warehouse
            group by prodname
        ) w
            on o.RequiredProdName = w.prodname
    ) a
),
cte as (
    select orderno, requiredprodname, rn_order, stock, demand, remaining
    from orders1
    --where rn_order=1
  UNION ALL
    SELECT
        o.orderno, o.requiredprodname, o.rn_order, o.stock, c.demand, 
        c.remaining + c.stock - o.demand AS remaining
    FROM orders1 o
    INNER JOIN CTE c
        ON c.requiredprodname != o.requiredprodname
    AND c.rn_order = o.rn_order - 1
)
SELECT *
from cte;
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried and your ONE challenge with that so we may help you fix it - generally this site is not a get new code coding platform but a help YOU fix YOUR code.   i.e. **put the code IN the question even if it is somewhere else** so if that "else" goes away later your question still has value to others. Also add a sample of the desired output not just a description of that

Comment: Don't worry about votes, worry about putting a copy of the code IN the question. (was not me BTW)  Links to the dbfiddle are fine but what if that changes or goes away...hence my comment. **Show sample desired output here**

Comment: I also put în db fidele the ddl and dml I put also the tables seppararlly as you  may see in the question  I have explain the requirements.this taslk is overkilling for me so pleaer bear wiith me.thank you

Comment: What if you have two orders that require overlapping products but the quantity is such that only one order can be fulfilled. Which of the two orders is honored then? What if there are three such orders?

Comment: Hello @SalmanA  The first order in order will be honored.
In our case, we have the first order that can be honored, the 2nd order not but the 3rd yes.
I hope I answered your question.

Comment: While parsing your query, I found a condition `AND o.requiredprodname != o.requiredprodname` that I presume should be `AND c.requiredprodname != o.requiredprodname`. I suggest that you review and correct as you make other improvements to the question.

Comment: @Florin - Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CTjpeHl_) containing your data, query (with 1 fix) and current results. Please take a look and then update your question with (1) your expected results, (2) how they differ from the current actual results, (3) what you believe the problem is, and (4) perhaps a description of your overall approach and logic. (Bear in mind that those willing to help are coming in cold and the better and more precisely you can explain your problem, the more likely you will have a favorable answer.)

Comment: @Florin - Should the previously mentioned condition actually be `o.requiredprodname = c.requiredprodname`? You are calculating `c.remaining + c.stock - o.demand AS remaining` in the associated select, so I would expect `c` and `o` to be matching products.

Comment: @TN My attemp is not correct- the logic is not correct but i really don t know how to get even close to the correct output.the code need changes.that s way i ask for help.
What i have tried and my attemp does not bring my to the correct output which should be orrd001 and ord003.
Thank you so much for taking time and trying to solve my question

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: @Squirrel Hello the expected output is ord001 and ord003.We can fulfill this 2 orders because we have the products for them in the warehouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a *very* deep dive into this problem, my conclusion is:

1. **It is doable** using a recursive CTE with with a great deal of effort and lots of tricky coding.
2. **Don't do it.** The resulting query is extremely complex, difficult to read and comprehend, is probably not efficiently scalable to large data sets, and would be a nightmare for you and those who may come after you to maintain.

**Just say no.** Instead look into developing an iterative procedural solution that considers and processes one order at a time.

If you really want to see what I came up with, here is the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UP33r4Bw).  I've added quite a few comments, but I expect it would be a challenge for anyone other than a senior, experienced SQL programmer to understand, and even that is a reach.

PLAN A:

My initial plan was to follow your lead and generate a recursive CTE with rows for each combination or order and product. Each CTE row would have dependencies on earlier rows.

Unfortunately, these CTE dependencies do not form a linear path. The updated remaining quantity for a product not only depends on the prior inventory for that product, but on the calculated fulfilment for that order, which in turn depends on all of the current product quantity requests, and all of the prior order remaining inventory quantities.

Ultimately this results in in a one-to-many CTE back-reference dependencies, which is not allowed in SQL server. Even is all back references refer to rows from previous recursion cycles, they are still disallowed.

PLAN B:

Since the only critical piece if information that must be calculated in sequence is the fulfillment flag, I took another stab and a recursive CTE that only results in one row per order and only records the fulfillment flag. Subsequent order calculations could recalculate the remaining inventory from scratch, based on initial inventory, knowledge of earlier-fulfilled orders, and the products allocated to those prior fulfilled orders.

Unfortunately, the same recursive CTE limitation came into play. Each recursive CTE row calculation not only needs to access the prior row, but all prior rows to identify all prior fulfilled orders. Again this is not allowed in SQL server.

PLAN C:

The next approach was to generate a recursive CTE, one per order, that not only sets the fulfillment flag, but also maintains a complete inventory of remaining quantities. A comma separated list was selected to represent the inventory. (XML or JSON might have been workable alternatives.)

Each CTE iteration would unpack the inventory, perform apply the order logic, update the inventory, and pack the results back into a comma-separated list.

Fitting this all into the CTE recursion query involved several nested queries, multiple CROSS APPLYs, and logic to pull the results back together.

Again SQL Server recursive CTE limitations kicked in. Recursive CTEs do not allow `OUTER JOIN`s. They do not allow `GROUP BY`. They do not allow *aggregate functions* like `STRING_JOIN()`. I even tried a `DISTINCT` in one lame attempt - not allowed.

I was finally able to fall back on the old `FOR XML` string aggregation technique and together with a few other klugy techniques, was able to get a working CTE.

The results are not anything that I would ever offer for production use for reasons summarized at the top of this post.

***I only post this as a lesson that sometimes going to extreme measures to get a job done using the wrong tools yields a barely workable and completely unmaintainable result, and that the better solution is to take a step back and reevaluate the task and look for a better tool set.***

Comment: Thank you so much for all the effort in solving this

Comment: One last request please because i just saw the answer - is this prior used the equivalent of the connect by prior in oracle? I admit that is for the first time when i see this in sql server and i thank you for that.

Comment: Didn't read your answer but I have done something similar in the past in a scripting language. You could use SP with cursors. The idea is to build a copy of inventory table with counts of each product, then process the orders in a loop (using cursor). If an order could be processed based on the "current" status of the inventory, `update` the counts otherwise skip. Proceed to next order. But yes, don't do it in SQL.

Comment: @Florin`- I am not an Oracle programmer, so my knowledge of "connect by" is limited to what I just looked up through google. It seems like recursive CTEs might have some overlapping behaviors with hierarchical queries, but I can't intelligently comment beyond that. I think of this problem as being like an excel spreadsheet, where cells on a row depend not only on the cells immediately above (prior inventory), but also also on the Fulfilled flag that is dependent on both multiple cells in the current row and multiple cells on the prior row. I think this qualifies as a partially ordered graph.

Comment: Thank you.i ve asked about the prior that you used în the solution because it was for the first time when I saw prior used în a sql server query.

Comment: My use of `PRIOR` was just a descriptive alias that I chose in the recursive part of the CTE, not a keyword in this context.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution and I want to share with you all. We take first order and see if the quantity of each and every ItemNo from this order is found in the Inventory table in sufficient quantity. If yes we flag it with selected 1 else we flag all the order 1 with selected=0. If we flag it with 1 as selected then all the ItemNo will receive an ItemId and the order will be sent to client but if we have flagged it with 0 we will ignore all the ItemNo required by this order and proceed to the next order. Similarly we will do for the next orders with the alocated numbers 2, 3, ... n as they where ordered by OrderID. For each i>=2 and i<=n (last order placed) we will calculate for each ItemNo from this order the necessary quentity on the order , the total quantity in Inventory and the already allocated quantity in the orders already analised ( from 1 to i-1 from temp1 ) but only those flagged with selected=1 in temp 1. If we find that an ItemNo from order i can't be honoured as it does not have enough quantity then we will flag all order with 0 in temp1 but if all ItemNo where having selected=1 then all order i will have selected as 1.

````
       create or alter view o1 as
       select top 100 percent OrderID, RequiredItemNo,
       count(*) as cant , 
       dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY OrderID) as nr1
       from orders  
        group by OrderID, RequiredItemNo
        order by OrderID, RequiredItemNo;

        create or alter view o1f as
        select OrderID, min(selected) as selected
        from
         (
          select  or1.OrderID, or1.RequiredItemNo, 1 selected from o1 or1
          where exists (select i.ItemNo from Inventory i 
             where i.ItemNo=or1.RequiredItemNo 
             group by i.ItemNo
             having count(*)>=or1.cant) and or1.nr1=1
          union all
          select  or1.OrderID, or1.RequiredItemNo, 0 selected from o1 or1
           where not exists (select i.ItemNo from Inventory i 
                   where i.ItemNo=or1.RequiredItemNo 
                      group by i.ItemNo
                      having count(*)>=or1.cant) and or1.nr1=1
              )a
           group by OrderID;

        CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE CalculateSelectedItems
        AS
         BEGIN
          IF OBJECT_ID('temp1') IS NOT NULL
          DROP TABLE temp1;
           CREATE TABLE temp1 (
           OrderIDnr INT,
            selected INT
           );
         DECLARE
             @vnr INT,
             @vselected INT,
             @i INT,
             @n INT;

          SET NOCOUNT ON;

          DELETE FROM temp1;
          SET @vnr = 1;

       SELECT @vselected = selected FROM o1f;
       INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES (@vnr, @vselected);

     SELECT @n = COUNT(DISTINCT OrderID) FROM orders;
     SET @i = 2;

     WHILE (@n >= @i)
     BEGIN
      SET @vnr = @i;
      SET @vselected = 2;

      SELECT @vselected = ISNULL(s.selected, 0)
      FROM (
        SELECT MIN(CAST(sel.selected AS INT)) AS selected
        FROM (
        SELECT or1.OrderID, or1.RequiredItemNo, '1' AS selected
        FROM o1 or1
        WHERE EXISTS (
            SELECT i.ItemNo
            FROM Inventory i 
            WHERE i.ItemNo = or1.RequiredItemNo 
            GROUP BY i.ItemNo
            HAVING COUNT(*) - or1.cant - (
                SELECT ISNULL(SUM(cant), 0)
                FROM o1
                INNER JOIN temp1 ON o1.RequiredItemNo = i.ItemNo 
                    AND o1.nr1 = temp1.OrderIDnr 
                    AND temp1.selected = 1
            ) >= 0
        ) AND or1.nr1 = @vnr
        
        UNION ALL
        
        SELECT or1.OrderID, or1.RequiredItemNo, '0' AS selected
        FROM o1 or1
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT i.ItemNo
            FROM Inventory i 
            WHERE i.ItemNo = or1.RequiredItemNo 
            GROUP BY i.ItemNo
            HAVING COUNT(*) - or1.cant - (
                SELECT ISNULL(SUM(cant), 0)
                FROM o1
                INNER JOIN temp1 ON o1.RequiredItemNo = i.ItemNo 
                    AND o1.nr1 = temp1.OrderIDnr 
                    AND temp1.selected = 1
            ) >= 0
        ) AND or1.nr1 = @vnr
    ) sel
    GROUP BY sel.OrderID
) s;
      INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES (@vnr, @vselected);
     SET @i = @i + 1;
     END;
     select * from temp1
      END;


      exec CalculateSelectedItems

  ```
````

Answer (score 0):

If some MSSQL experienced user can convert this one from ORACLE syntax, at least it seems to work:

```
with orders(id, reqproduct) as (
    select 'ORD001', 'Prod007' from dual union all
    select 'ORD001', 'Prod008' from dual union all
    select 'ORD001', 'Prod009' from dual union all
    select 'ORD002', 'Prod008' from dual union all
    select 'ORD002', 'Prod009' from dual union all
    select 'ORD002', 'Prod012' from dual union all
    select 'ORD003', 'Prod008' from dual union all
    select 'ORD003', 'Prod014' from dual 
),
warehouse(product) as (
    select 'Prod007' from dual union all
    select 'Prod008' from dual union all
    select 'Prod008' from dual union all
    select 'Prod012' from dual union all
    select 'Prod009' from dual union all
    select 'Prod014' from dual union all
    select 'Prod015' from dual 
),
gwarehouse(product, qty) as (
    select product, count(*) from warehouse group by product
),
porders as (
    select row_number() over(order by ord.id) as rn, ord.id 
    from orders ord
        join gwarehouse war on ord.reqproduct = war.product 
        group by ord.id having( count(*) = (select count(*) from orders ord1 where ord1.id = ord.id))
)
,cte(rn, id, remqty, excluded) as 
(
    select pord.rn, ord.id, war.qty - 1, 
        listagg(
            case when war.qty - 1 = 0 then ord.reqproduct end, ','
        ) within group(order by ord.reqproduct) over(partition by ord.id )
    from porders pord
    join orders ord on pord.id = ord.id
    join gwarehouse war on war.product = ord.reqproduct
    where pord.rn = 1

    union all
    
    select pord.rn, pord.id, c.remqty - 1, 
        c.excluded || ',' || 
        listagg( 
            distinct 
            case when (c.remqty - 1 = 0 or war.qty - 1 = 0) and instr(c.excluded, ord.reqproduct) = 0
            then 
                ord.reqproduct 
            end, ','
        ) within group(order by ord.reqproduct) over(partition by ord.id)       
    from cte c
    join porders pord on pord.rn >= c.rn + 1
    join orders ord on ord.id = pord.id 
    join gwarehouse war on war.product = ord.reqproduct 
    where not exists (
        select 1 from orders ord1 where ord1.id = ord.id and instr(excluded, ord1.reqproduct) > 0 
    )
)
select distinct id from cte
;


ORD001
ORD003
```

Comment: Even if the solution is in oracle is very helpful.
Thank you so much for taking time and provideing an answer.

Comment: I tested the solution and unfortunately it doesn't work because I added another product009 and in this case it should have shown ord001 and ord002 but it shows that all the orders have been fulfilled - ord003 could not be fulfilled. 
I will try to figure out what can i change.
Thank you very much for the answer

Comment: Ok, if you add a "lvl" column increased by 1 at each recursion level and "select distinct lvl, id from cte) you will get 3 rows "1 ORD001, 2 ORD002, 2 ORD003" which means it founds 2 solutions "(ORD001; ORD002)" and "(ORD001; ORD003)", so you just need to add way to select the only one you want.

Comment: Ok thank you i will do that.BTW i vote for your answer. I appreciate every effort

Comment: In fact if you remove the condition "where pord.rn = 1" from the anchor of the recursive query, you will then get 3 possible solutions: ORD001/ORD002, ORD001/ORD003, ORD002/ORD003.

Comment: Be careful that to be able to identify the solutions in a larger data set you may have to add some more columns like building the "path" ...